# Existence of a celestial body big enough for early civilization to be thought of as a second moon

Tags: space, earth-like

Is there a possible scenario in which once a year a celestial body can be seen from the surface of the Earth-like planet for a short period of time?

- With it being big enough for early civilization to consider it a second moon but much smaller than the actual one.
- And occurring each year for one thousand years.

I thought two moons questions are similar enough, but I haven't found a proper answer for myself.

Thank you!

Comment: Humans considered *all* celestial bodies to be going around the Earth until a chap named [Copernicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaus_Copernicus) (and some of his contemporaries) suggested otherwise.  I doubt the size would make a difference or periodicity.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  What do you mean by "occurring for 1,000 years"?  Do you mean the moon is in the sky, visible and basically the same size, for a 1,000 year period, or that the inhabitants see it once every 1,000 years, like a comet?

Comment: @StephenG true, but not all of them were considered moons.

Comment: @JBH thank you :) 
No, no, I want it to be much smaller to lessen the impact on the system. But what I mean is the ideal scenario for it to be visible once a year, each year, for 1,000 years.

Comment: Thanks, please [edit] your question with the clarification.  Never depend on people reading through the comments to find clarifications.  Cheers!

Comment: Just to say, it is custom here to wait 24 hours after asking a question before awarding acceptance, otherwise it can discourage other, perhaps better answers - this policy benefits the comunity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. That would be a kind of quasi-satellite.

And Earth already has a small one - it's called [Cruithne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3753_Cruithne). At perigee, a larger Cruithne might well be visible, always in the same section of the sky.

[image]

A larger body would be less stable, but if you only need one thousand years, I think it could work out.

As rightfully pointed out by Ville Niemi, in this context "less stable" might have very, very dire consequences - you might be looking at a [Theia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_(planet))-like endgame. Emphasis on the "end".

Comment: Just wanted to point out this despite it not being in the question. I think the "failure mode" for this solution would be pretty bad. I mean, if I had bought this solution from a world building agency I would want my money back or at least **very** good insurance for my civilization bundled in the deal.

Comment: @VilleNiemi, is there such a real thing as a "world building agency", or is that just a Douglas Adams style joke?

Comment: @EveryBitHelps Obviously building planet scale objects to specification requires highly specialized equipment and expertise. Simple economics requires it is handled by an organization specialized in it.

Comment: @VilleNiemi damn, here I though there where some ppl offering dedicated wb services to help with our geeky hobbies! Besides those of us here on wb.se.

Answer (score 11):

A **comet** could fill this role.  Comets are notoriously bright.

[image: comet]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Comet_P1_McNaught02_-_23-01-07.jpg

I like the tail but you could have your celestial body be made of something more solid, equally reflective, but not falling apart and leaving the tail.

Comets also have very elliptical orbits and visit infrequently.  In this [list of periodic comets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_periodic_comets), 3200 Phaeton has a period of 1.4 years - very short by comet standards.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3200_Phaethon

[image: 3200 phaeton orbit]

So: your second moon is a very bright short period comet.  That seems plausible.

Comment: This could work, but probably not for very long - a short period comet would have less volatiles, and likely not last for one thousand years (and a large comet would be less stable). But yes, especially if it came from outside the ecliptic, it would be plausible and is a much better solution than a 'quasi-satellite'.
( https://www.thenakedscientists.com/articles/questions/how-quickly-will-comet-evaporate )